# Show that a self-complementary graph contains an odd number of vertices with degree $(n-1)/2$

Tags: graph-theory

Does anyone know how to prove that a self-complementary graph contains an odd number of vertices with degree $(n-1)/2$?

Thanks for the help :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not true if $n$ is even. Consider the graph $G$ with vertex set $\{1,2,3,4\}$ and edges $12,23$, and $34$; its complement has edges $24,41$, and $13$. Both graphs are simply paths of length $3$, so $G$ is self-complementary. However, $n=4$, so $\frac{n-1}2=\frac32$, and $G$ clearly has zero vertices of degree $\frac32$. Zero is an even number.

The result is true if $n$ is odd, however.

HINT: Let $G$ be a self-complementary graph with $n$ vertices.

- Explain why $\deg_G(v)+\deg_{\overline{G}}v=n-1$ for each vertex $v$ of $G$.
- Use this observation to show if $0\le k\le n-1$, and $G$ has $\ell$ vertices of degree $k$, then $G$ must also have $\ell$ vertices of degree $n-1-k$.
- Conclude that $G$ must have an even number of vertices whose degrees are *not* equal to $\frac{n-1}2$, and use the hypothesis that $n$ is odd to get the desired conclusion.

Comment: The questions sais that n=1(mod 4). Sorry for not mentioning this before.

Comment: @TheDeC: Okay. That makes $n$ odd, so you can simply ignore everything before the hint.

Comment: @brian-m-scott: How does having an even number of vertices whose degrees are not equal to $(n-1)/2$ leads us to the fact that there is an odd number of vertices with that particular degree?
I mean, how can we be sure that there are vertices with that degree?

Comment: @TheDeC: Every vertex has a degree that either is or is not $(n-1)/2$. the total number of vertices is odd, an even number of vertices have degrees not equal to $(n-1)/2$, and an odd number minus an even number is ... ?